# How to split REST APIs into projects?

Tags: rest, web-services

We¨re going to implement REST APIs piece by piece in different projects (and corresponding applets). Ideally, the REST API URLs should look like this (simplified example):

```
/customers
/customers/{cid}
/customets/{cid}/products
/customers/{cid}/products/{pid}
etc.
```

But the API for customers will be implemented in Project1 (as Applet1) and the API for products in Project2 (as Applet2). Due to technical reasons, each applet can be configured to handle one or a few URLs of this form:

```
/customers/*
/customers/*/products/*
```

but the shorter URL pattern takes always precedence, so that the second URL will never apply. Hence, it seems we have to end with a URL structure as follows:

```
/Project1/customers
/Project1/customers/{cid}
/Project2/customers/{cid}/products
/Project2/customers/{cid}/products/{pid}
```

which is not ideal at all.

**Is there is better solution?**

Comment: Not making a catch-all route (`/customers/*`), but a constrained one (`/customers/[0-9]+`).

Comment: Do you mean Java Applets!?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Unfortunately, the tool does not support regular expessions, only "*" as a wildcard.

Comment: Get a better tool then.

Comment: @LutzHorn: No, in fact we use IBM Integration Bus. However, I do not consider this information important for the question, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @CodeCaster: This is not a good advice. Every tool has its problems, but other tool has another problems. IBM Integration Bus cannot be replaced easily by something else.

Comment: Don't you think the use of that particular tool and its limitations was worth mentioning? I'm sure you can configure some kind of precedence, so that the more specific route gets matched first.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I've experimented with this a lot, I even know how IIB represents the URL bindings internally, and I'm almost 100% sure the pattern precedence cannot be set.